# ¿Cómo obtener el menor valor de un array sin tener en cuenta el 0?

Tags: java

¿óomo puedo sacar el menor valor de un `array` pero que que este sea distinto de cero (0) pro ejemplo ingreso en un vector `(1,2,3,0)` el menor debería ser `1` .

tengo el código que saca el valor mínimo pero quiero que discrimine el cero si acaso el lo ingresara

```
public int menor1() {

    int menor1;
    int pos;
    menor1= num[0];
    pos=0;
    for(int f=1;f< num.length;f++) {
        if ( num[f]<menor1) {
            menor1= num[f];
            pos=f;
        }
    }
    return menor1;
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué intentaste? por favor añada el código

Comment: Porfavor e añadido una imgen con lo que tengo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es que no tenga en cuenta el 0 podrías agregar otra condición a tu if.

Tu ejemplo modificado:

```
public int menor1() {
    int menor1;
    int pos;
    menor1= num[0];
    pos=0;
    for(int f=1;f< num.length;f++) {
       if ( num[f]<menor1 && num[f] != 0 || menor1 == 0) {
          menor1= num[f];
          pos=f;
       }
    }

    return menor1;
}
```

Comment: Ow muchas gracias era tan sencillo como eso me has salvado

Comment: @Mariano Si, creo que es lo más correcto. Realmente ahora estaba mirando esta solución pero estaba mirando todas las posibilidades que había por si se me escapaba alguna. Bien visto lo del primer cero ;)

Answer (score 0):

Con Java 8 y sus `Stream` es todavía más idiomático:

```
return Arrays.stream(num)        // crear un stream
            .filter(i -> i != 0) // eliminar los ceros
            .min()               // elegir el menor
            .orElse(0);          // si ha ocurrido un error devolver 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Con Java 8 y Stream y para números negativos:

```
import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        long[] ldata = {-1,2,2,3,4,-3,-5,-7,-2};

        long valor = Arrays.stream(ldata).reduce((x,y) -> (Math.abs(x)>Math.abs(y))?y:x).orElse(0);

        System.out.println(valor + "");

    }
}
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y explica brevemente el funcionamiento de este código. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.